# Разбор адресов на составляющие

Tags: python

Имеется список адресов, например:

```
Абрамцевская улица, дом 16 Б
ул. Абрамцевская, д.3
ул Абрамцевская 5
Абрамцевская ул., 5/2
```

Имеется так же класс:

```
class Address:
    def __init__(self, type, type_house, number_house):
        self.type = type # улица или шоссе
        self.name = name # название улицы
        self.type_house = 'дом' 
        self.number_house = number_house # все, что справа от названия улицы
```

Как разбить строки на составляющие поля класса `Address`? Пробую делать через split по знакам деление слов в строке, далее циклом перебираю получившийся список на поиск ключевых слов, таких, как `ул, улица` итд. потом ищу по ключевому слову `дом, д`. В зависимости от индекса элемента или его отсутствия нахожу название улицы. Как то очень все не уклюже получается, может у кого то есть варианты реализации более интересные

Comment: А откуда Вы берете список адресов в таком виде?

Comment: Я просто к чему спрашиваю. Если вам это для дела а не для поиграться, есть прекрасный сервис с замечетельным api. Как раз на этот и подобные случаи. До 10к запросов в сутки - халява. DaData называется. Парсит любые адреса. Есть либа под питон

Comment: Слышал о таком, мне интересно, как это в питоне выглядеть будет, работа со строками индексами итд

Comment: Тогда удачи в этом нелегком. ) Все через это проходят ). Не думаю чтобы для качественного решения задачи вы смогли ограничиться перечисленным инструментарием, но чем черт не шутит...

Comment: Ещё как вариант можно взять парсер адресов из библиотеки `Natasha`, тут вроде было про неё несколько ответов, можно поиском поискать. Самому такой парсер писать - задача очень муторная.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть готовая библиотека [Natasha](https://github.com/natasha/natasha) для подобных задач (извлечения фактов из текста), но она довольно заметно изменилась с тех пор, как я с ней пробовал работать. Куда-то дели парсер адресов, приходится ставить старую версию, как рекомендуют в README:

> API may change, for realworld tasks consider using low level libraries from Natasha project. Models optimized for news articles, quality on other domain may be lower. To use old `NamesExtractor`, `AddressExtactor` downgrade `pip install natasha<1 yargy<0.13`

У меня установилось в таком варианте команды (нужно взять в кавычки, т.к. знак `<` - оператор перенаправления ввода)

```
pip install "natasha<1" "yargy<0.13"
```

Примерный код:

```
from natasha import AddressExtractor

extractor = AddressExtractor()

addresses = """
Абрамцевская улица, дом 16 Б
ул. Абрамцевская, д.3
ул Абрамцевская 5
Абрамцевская ул., 5/2
""".strip().splitlines()

for address in addresses:
    matches = extractor(address)
    for match in matches:
        print(match.fact)
```

Вывод:

```
Address(parts=[Street(name='Абрамцевская', type='улица'), Building(number='16 Б', type='дом')])
Address(parts=[Street(name='Абрамцевская', type='улица'), Building(number='3', type='дом')])
Address(parts=[Street(name='Абрамцевская', type='улица'), Building(number='5', type=None)])
Address(parts=[Street(name='Абрамцевская', type='улица'), Building(number='5/2', type=None)])
```

Дальше для заполнения вашего объекта нужно пройти по списку в поле `parts` извлеченного адреса, у каждого элемента проверить тип, прописать в соответствующее поле вашего объекта.

Если возникнут трудности с этим, я позже могу набросать пример, как это сделать.

---

**UPD.** Оказалось, что парсер адресов теперь называется `AddrParser`, но на ваших данных он не всегда находит номер дома, так что возможно имеет смысл использовать более старую версию. Пример кода (версия `natasha == 1.4.0`):

```
from natasha import AddrExtractor
import pymorphy2

morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()
extractor = AddrExtractor(morph)

addresses = """
Абрамцевская улица, дом 16 Б
ул. Абрамцевская, д.3
ул Абрамцевская 5
Абрамцевская ул., 5/2
""".strip().splitlines()


for address in addresses:
    matches = extractor(address)
    print([match.fact for match in matches])
```

Вывод:

```
[AddrPart(value='Абрамцевская', type='улица'), AddrPart(value='16 Б', type='дом')]
[AddrPart(value='Абрамцевская', type='улица'), AddrPart(value='3', type='дом')]
[AddrPart(value='Абрамцевская', type='улица')]
[AddrPart(value='Абрамцевская', type='улица')]
```